# Setting the type/creator code programmatically

Tags: c, macos, macos-carbon

I am trying to set the type/creator codes as shown below, but this causes the finder flags and label to get messed up.

```
FSCatalogInfo catInfo;
FSGetCatalogInfo(&fileRef, kFSCatInfoFinderInfo, &catInfo, NULL, NULL, NULL);
FileInfo *info = (FileInfo*)catInfo.finderInfo;
info->fileCreator = 'ar12';
info->fileType = 'rsrc';
FSSetCatalogInfo(&fileRef, kFSCatInfoFinderInfo, &catInfo);
```

What am I doing wrong, and how should I be doing it?

Answer (score 3):

Your code snippet works fine for me. Label and finder flags are not changed.

```
g5:fileinfotest toby$ touch the-file
g5:fileinfotest toby$ GetFileInfo the-file
file: "/Volumes/data/Users/toby/Documents/workspace/fileinfotest/the-file"
type: ""
creator: ""
attributes: avbstclinmedz
created: 02/23/2011 14:29:15
modified: 02/23/2011 14:29:15

g5:fileinfotest toby$ ./build/Debug/fileinfotest.app/Contents/MacOS/fileinfotest 

g5:fileinfotest toby$ GetFileInfo the-file
file: "/Volumes/data/Users/toby/Documents/workspace/fileinfotest/the-file"
type: "EFGh"
creator: "ABCd"
attributes: avbstclinmedz
created: 02/23/2011 14:29:15
modified: 02/23/2011 14:29:15
```

Code:

```
FSCatalogInfo catInfo;
FSRef ref;

if(!FSPathMakeRef (
               "/Volumes/data/Users/toby/Documents/workspace/fileinfotest/the-file",
               &ref,
               false
                   ))
{
    FSGetCatalogInfo(&ref, kFSCatInfoFinderInfo, &catInfo, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    FileInfo *info = (FileInfo*)catInfo.finderInfo;
    info->fileCreator = 'ABCd';
    info->fileType = 'EFGh';
    FSSetCatalogInfo(&ref, kFSCatInfoFinderInfo, &catInfo);
}
```